# Open Graph data with php

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph, title

I friend asked me if i can write something in PHP. I'm new to websripting languages. 
I need the URL from the page and write the correct meta tag for it. I also want to have the html  element in a meta tag for the open graph protocol...

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <?php 
    $meta_close = '"/>'."\n"."\t";

    //get url from page, found code on stackoverflow
    $link =  "http//www.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $escaped_link = htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $meta_url1 = '<meta property="og:url" content="';

    //get page <title> element, found on stackoverflow 
    $pattern = "/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
    $meta_title1 ='<meta property="og:title" content="Zee-Online|';


    echo "".$meta_url1.$escaped_link.$meta_close;
    echo "".$meta_title1.$match[1].$meta_close;  //problem here? 



    ?>    
    </head>
```

This is the result:

```
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="http//www.woodworking-creations.be/test.php"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Zee-Online |"/>
```

In the title property, this script doesn't append the title (in this case "test")
Should have this

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http//www.woodworking-creations.be/test.php"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Zee-Online | test"/>
```

And another problem, and that's why i try this: "Zee-online" is a local news site. If we share an article, it's alwas the wrong picture. I think i need to get all the images on the page, and add a meta tag for each of them? How to? Facebook always shows a picture of one of our volunteers. We have added a meta tag for the image, so now always or logo shows up. But we want to be able to show one of the images in the article, if available.

(Zee-online is on www.zee-online.be, but i'm not the administrator, so i tried it on my own website with a test page)

Comment: why are you using meta tags?

Comment: `$string` is undefined. Theoretically, `$string` would contain the page contents you're scraping, but the file would have to scrape its own output. You can do this with [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), but you shouldn't. Save the title in a variable once and print it out twice (once in the `<title>` and once in a `<meta>`).

Comment: We can't write the <title> with a variable, since the webpage is made with Drupal....